# Download multiple images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i have to display 11 images in single cell ,all that images are downloaded from server, so when my tableview show than i wanna download all images from server & display it in custom cell. I have used lazyloading sample code. But t can download 1 image at a time. it not feasible according to my requirement. Is there any way to solve this problem???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a thread for every image you download from the server using -

> ```
> [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(downloadImage:) toTarget:self withObject:@"Image URL"];
> ```

1. Send a request to the server to retrieve the image using a thread block.

> ```
> -(void)downloadImage:(NSString *)inURL {
>         NSAutoreleasePool *thePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
>         UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:inURl]];
>         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(uploadImage:) withObject:theImage waitUntilDone:NO];
>         [thePool drain];
>     }
> ```

1. Update the image so you may view it. A view can only be changed by the main thread.

> ```
> -(void)uploadImage:(UIImage *)inImage {
>     [inImage retain]; // add image to View.[inImage relese];
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I like using [ASIHTTPRequest and ASINetworkQueue](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) for downloading many items concurrently, it's very simple yet powerful and extendable. You'll get the request finished callbacks one at a time and can display the images as they are downloaded, you can also easily track the progress of individual downloads and of the queue as a whole.

> Using an NSOperationQueue (or ASINetworkQueue, see below) you create
>   yourself gives you more control over asynchronous requests. When using
>   a queue, only a certain number of requests can run at the same time.
>   If you add more requests than the queue’s maxConcurrentOperationCount
>   property, requests will wait for others to finish before they start.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you call your server side code only once; you need to call it once for every image you want to download.
If you use delegates you have to call it for all the images you want to download.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, for downloading multiple images at the same time (which is what you are trying to achieve) you have to implement image download request in threads.

Send a notification when download completes and handle the same to load the newly downloaded image on your UI.

Best of luck..!